# TextButton onpress() not working om flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

so I tried to link 2 screens in flutter together via a Textbutton but it won't work.

This is my code for my Text Button :

```
TextButton(
                child: Text(
                  "New Page",
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
                  );
                },
              ),
```

The Button itself shows and displays properly, but when I press on the button, I get this on my debug console and the screen stays the same.

Debug Console :

```
#3      MyApp.build.<anonymous closure>
package:layoutesting/main.dart:48
#4      _InkResponseState._handleTap
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:991
...
Handler: "onTap"
Recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer#f8109
    debugOwner: GestureDetector
    state: possible
    won arena
    finalPosition: Offset(218.4, 512.8)
    finalLocalPosition: Offset(42.4, 10.8)
    button: 1
    sent tap down
```

Also this is my code for my second screen. (Straight from the flutter website) :

```
class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Route"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, (**Btw both of my pages are a stateless widget**).

THANKS!

(FULL FIRST WIDGET CODE) :

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.red,
                height: 792,
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    child: Text(
                      "New Page",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.blue,
                height: 792,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi There. The issue issue probably in your first widget. Post it's full code. Since I used the parts you posted here and it's working perfectily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `context` you are using for `Navigator.push(context,...)` is above your `MaterialApp` widget and contains no reference for a `Navigator` since the navigator is set up by the `MaterialApp`.

You need a new `context` that is under the `MaterialApp` to allow your `Navigator` to be found.

Either wrap your `Scaffold` in a `Builder` widget for a new context or make a new separate `FirstWidget`.

### Method 1: Builder

```dart
home: Builder(
  builder: (ctx) => Scaffold(
    ...,
    TextButton(
      ...,
      onPressed: (){
        Navigator.push(ctx,...); //<-- Use the new ctx from Builder
      }
    ),
  ),  
),
```

### Method 2: new Widget (Preferred)

```dart
class FirstWidget extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(...);
}
```

Then use this inside `home` argument:

```dart
MaterialApp(
  home: FirstWidget(),
)
```